# Grouping rows in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have created a table on front end with several columns. The table with data looks something like below:

```
    ID         Name          Date1           Date2         Code1    
   00001        abc         2012/1/1         2012/1/10       1
   00002        def         2012/1/12        2012/2/1        1
   00002        def         2012/1/12        2012/2/1        2
   00002        def         2012/1/12        2012/2/1        3
   00003        xyz         2012/2/12        2012/3/1        2
   00003        xyz         2012/2/12        2012/3/1        4
```

Now I want to present data in above table in grouped manner i.e. every unique Id has only 1 row and all the code columns merged and displayed as 1 row.

```
    ID         Name          Date1           Date2         Code1    
   00001        abc         2012/1/1         2012/1/10       1
                                                             1
   00002        def         2012/1/12        2012/2/1        2                              
                                                             3
   00003        xyz         2012/2/12        2012/3/1        2
                                                             4
```

Please ignore my formatting style. Is this possible to do it programmatic when I do not have information about the number of code values coming? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will remove the contents of cells which duplicate the content of the cell above them. It won't merge them (à la `rowspan` / `colspan`), but it will empty them.

```
function emptyDittoCells(table) {
    if (!(table instanceof jQuery && table.is("table")))
        throw "bad parameter";

    table.find('tr').each(function(rowElement) {
        var row = $(rowElement);
        var previousRow = $(rowElement).prev('tr');
        if (!previousRow.length) return;

        row.each(function(cellElement, index) {
            var cell = $(cellElement);
            var previousCell = previousRow.children("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); 

            while (previousCell.data('ditto')) {
                previousCell = previousCell.data('ditto');
            }

            if (hasSameContents(cell, previousCell)) {
                cell.empty()
                    .data('ditto', previousCell);
            }
        });
    });
}

function hasSameContents(a, b) {
    return (a.text() == b.text()); // naive but usable in the simple case
}
```

untested and a little DOM-intensive, but I think it'll work.  Besides possible syntax errors (missing close-parentheses), I'm mostly concerned about that `td:nth-child()` selector.  That could be written more robustly as `$(previousRow.children('td').get(index))`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly is possible.

Depending on the constraints on the table (e.g. are the ID strictly increasing?) several algorithms can be thought of that accomplish exactly what you ask.

But, I would highly recommend against it. Doing this using jQuery directly on the DOM would require a lot of DOM access operations and would be relatively slow.
It would be much, much better to do this either on the server-side, where I suppose the data is generated, or otherwise on the clientside on a array/object representation of the same data.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said before, these kind of transformations are better accomplished on server side.

But if the table is not too big, and assuming that Name, Date1 and Date2 have the same values for a given ID, you can parse the table (using jQuery, for example) and rebuild it from scratch.

Some pseudocode:

```
foreach (row)
{
  foreach (column)
  {
    get ID value;
    if (not yet stored) store data for that ID somewhere else;
    store Code1 value with its ID;
  }
}

foreach (ID stored)
{
  get all related values;
  rebuild table row;
}
```

I hope it helps. If doesn't, it would not be so difficult to write some jQuery code.